# Design reasons against directly cancelling draft building

Tags: game-design, ui-design

I am developing an RTS right now and this topic came up in discussion about the UI design and patterns in Starcraft 2:

When you issue a building command in any race, it will create a "draft" transparent model of the building that will be seen until the worker arrives at the location and the construction begins.

[image: screenshot showing building draft]

Once you deselect/lose track of the worker, though, there's no easy way to cancel such a building. One needs to manually locate the unit tasked with it and stop it.

Is there any design reason or implication of why the building drafts themselves aren't clickable? The only thing I can think of is that it would potentially allow modifying the action queue in the middle by cancelling a specific building - which isn't possible elsewhere.

I know that I can do whatever I want, but I was interested in potential design implications I might not be aware of.

Comment: I think this is just a simple oversight.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin I'm sure that someone would have brought this up over all the years the game has been out, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure and inconvenience one may find in starcraft 2, especially regarding ui and usability, is intentional - because they think it increases the skill cap and they probably just like to annoy their players.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning (but not a complete answer) - Age of Empires and its sequels *do* have selectable draft buildings, which can be cancelled, so it's not as though the idea has never been tried and can only be discussed hypothetically.

Answer (score 2):

Adding friction to cancelling a build as described increases the 'cost' of changing strategies with respect to the player's time & attention. Put another way, it draws the focus away from others things & may represent a bit of risk reward. The player wants to change their mind about a course of action (building the structure that they now wish to cancel), but there may be varying degrees of certainty as to how long that will take. The worker needs to be located in order to cancel.

If the worker is on screen, the time required to cancel is probably negligible, but it may take slightly more time to click a moving worker as opposed to the static draft structure. If the worker is not on screen, there's the added time of locating the worker before it can be clicked.

Whether or not this aspect is relevant to your game depends on how meaningful this friction is to your design. In a single player game, a more casually paced game or a game based around fluidity of tactics, the friction might be a design liability. For games at the other ends of those spectrums, the friction might be desirable.

Comment: I think another useful consideration is: what becomes of the worker? Cancelling the building may leave them idling with no orders in the middle of nowhere - maybe even in neutral territory if the unit had to path around obstacles in an awkward way. So your next step is probably to go find the worker to give it an alternate order *anyway* - maybe a quick link to jump to the assigned worker is all you need?

Answer (score 2):

DMGregory brought up a good point in a comment on another answer: When the player cancels the build command, what happens to the worker unit? It would then have no order and just stand around. So unless the player wants to waste that worker, they need to find it and give it a new command anyway. That means canceling the build process at the location of the building would be a redundant action.

And then there is also an argument to be made about consistency. When the player wants to cancel an attack order, do they interact with the target? When the player wants to cancel a move order, do they interact with the destination? No, they interact with the unit they gave the command to. Why should building be any different?

Comment: What would you think of the draft building"s selection menu having a "Select/Go to assigned worker" button to ease the task of finding/catching that worker?

Comment: This is actually flawed logic. Stopping building and cancelling the build job entirely are two different things.